# Convert/Parsing XML to CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing

can someone here guide my how to convert this xml to csv using python 3.9? Currently im having hard time on how to parse this xml.

below is my xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE raml SYSTEM 'raml20.dtd'>
<raml version="2.0" xmlns="raml20.xsd">
  <cmData type="actual">
    <header>
      <log dateTime="2023-09-11T09:32:44.000+08:00" action="created" appInfo="ActualExporter">UIValues are used</log>
    </header>
    <managedObject class="LNCEL" version="FLF22R3_2207_10_2207_10" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-10000/LNBTS-100007/LNCEL-10" id="10000">
      <p name="mcc">100</p>
      <p name="mnc">20</p>
      <p name="name">Cell01</p>
      <p name="a1TimeToTriggerDeactInterMeas">320ms</p>
      <p name="a2RedirectQci1">disabled</p>
    </managedObject>
  </cmData>
</raml>
```

Output that i want to be like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK3hd.png

Thanks advance all, looking forward for your comments.

Comment: you can use this module to parse:  `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how you can parse the XML using [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup):

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("your_file.xml", "r") as f_in:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f_in.read(), "xml")

header = soup.header
dt = header.log["dateTime"]

all_data = []
for mo in soup.select("managedObject"):
    version = mo["version"]
    dist_name = mo["distName"]
    moid = mo["id"]
    all_data.append(
        {
            "DATETIME": dt,
            "VERSION": version,
            "DISTNAME": dist_name,
            "MOID": moid,
            **{p["name"]: p.text for p in mo.select("p") for a in p.attrs},
        }
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                        DATETIME                  VERSION                                     DISTNAME   MOID  mcc mnc    name a1TimeToTriggerDeactInterMeas a2RedirectQci1
0  2023-09-11T09:32:44.000+08:00  FLF22R3_2207_10_2207_10  PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-10000/LNBTS-100007/LNCEL-10  10000  100  20  Cell01                         320ms       disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using Python's xml.etree.ElementTree for XML parsing and Python's built-in csv module for writing CSV files. You need to parse the XML to extract the required data and write the extracted data to a CSV file. The code is given below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv
from datetime import datetime

xml_string = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE raml SYSTEM 'raml20.dtd'>
<raml version="2.0" xmlns="raml20.xsd">
  <cmData type="actual">
    <header>
      <log dateTime="2023-09-11T09:32:44.000+08:00" action="created" appInfo="ActualExporter">UIValues are used</log>
    </header>
    <managedObject class="LNCEL" version="FLF22R3_2207_10_2207_10" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-10000/LNBTS-100007/LNCEL-10" id="10000">
      <p name="mcc">100</p>
      <p name="mnc">20</p>
      <p name="name">Cell01</p>
      <p name="a1TimeToTriggerDeactInterMeas">320ms</p>
      <p name="a2RedirectQci1">disabled</p>
    </managedObject>
  </cmData>
</raml>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)

log_header = root.find('.//{raml20.xsd}log')
date_time = log_header.attrib.get('dateTime', '') if log_header is not None else ''

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    headers = ['MO', 'MO Name', 'mcc', 'mnc', 'name', 'a1TimeToTriggerDeactInterMeas', 'a2RedirectQci1', 'dateTime', 'MOID']
    csv_writer.writerow(headers)

    for mo in root.findall('.//{raml20.xsd}managedObject'):
        dist_name = mo.attrib['distName']
        version = mo.attrib['version']
        moid = mo.attrib.get('id', '') 
        properties = {p.attrib['name']: p.text for p in mo.findall('.//{raml20.xsd}p')}
        row_data = [
            date_time,
            version,
            dist_name,
            moid,
            properties.get('mcc', ''),
            properties.get('mnc', ''),
            properties.get('name', ''),
            properties.get('a1TimeToTriggerDeactInterMeas', ''),
            properties.get('a2RedirectQci1', '')
        ]
        csv_writer.writerow(row_data)
```